# Too large Other Volume in Container

Tags: macos, disk-volume

My Mac show disk full and realized that I can use only 100 GB (Out of 500 GB).
I checked Storage and realized that there are a lot of space for "Other Volume in Container".

[image]

So I check diskutil list in terminal and found below

[image: ainer]

I know APFS Volume disk1s5 and disk1s6 but I am not sure what is disk1s1.
It is not visualized it in DiskUtil also. Does someone know how to increase available volume?
Or how to delete that disk1s1 volume?

Below is the command result from "diskutil apfs list"

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I would think the 'diskutil apfs list' displays more than just disk1s1 can you update the question with the full listing?

Comment: Looks a bit like my dual boot configurations.  What if you hold Option while booting?  Do you see more than one option to boot?  The disk1s1 is encrypted and not mounted.

Comment: Did you try to erase this Mac previously?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple "Macintosh HD - Data" is a sure sign that Catalina has been installed more than once without erasing the whole physical disk.

You may be able to fix it by:

1. Backup all your data and settings to Time Machine (in case something goes wrong).
2. Discover using "diskutil apfs list" which of disk1s5 and disk1s6 is  mounted.
3. Boot into Recovery mode (reboot holding Cmd-R down).
4. Using Disk Utility, delete all but one of the multiple Data disks.  Keep only the one which was mounted in step 2.
5. Reboot as normal.
6. If this works, all good.  If not use the Second Way below.

Second Way:

1. Backup all your data and settings to Time Machine - this is essential.
2. Boot into Recovery mode (reboot holding Cmd-R down).
3. In Disk Utility make sure you can see all physical disks.  Do this by using the menu View and Show All Devices.
4. Erase the disk (not the volume) in Disk Utility.
5. Reinstall macOS.
6. Use Migration Assistant to recover all your data, apps and settings from Time Machine.

If you are not confident of doing this, take your Mac to a repair shop.

There are numerous examples on the web of people getting into this mess, and getting out of it!  For example: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250731491

Answer (score 0):

You can thirst delete the volume disk1s1 that is not mounted :

```
 diskutil ap deletevolume disk1s1
```

then between disk1s5 and disk1s6 there is a useless volume. To know the real data volume, give the result of :

```
diskutil ap listgroups disk1
```

Then you can delete the volume which does not appear in the list of the previous command :

```
diskutil ap deletevolume disk1sX
```

If you are not sure, give the result and I give you the real command.